# setcounter has a problem in double enumerate environments

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I got a problem in using the command `\setcounter{enumi}{}`, in double `enumerate` environment.

More precisely, I used an `enumerate` environment in another `enumerate` list.

To change the number of inner `enumerate`, I used `setcounter` command, but it worked in outer `enumerate` number.

Here is my minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is in outer enumerate environment.
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is in inner enumerate environment.
        \setcounter{enumi}{4}
        \item setcounter is used. %I want to make this item have index 5
    \end{enumerate}
    \item This will have index 5. %I want to keep the index of this item as default
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the default `enumerate` environment the counter at level `<x>` is represented by the counter `enum<x>`, where `<x>` is represented as a roman numeral. Level 1 therefore uses `enumi`, level 2 `enumii`, level 3 `enumiii`, ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item This is in outer enumerate environment.
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is in inner enumerate environment.
    \setcounter{enumii}{4}
    \item setcounter is used. %I want to make this item have index 5
  \end{enumerate}
  \item This will have index 3. %I want to keep the index of this item as default
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```